Backup/Clone Drive File Allication Table
I need a solution for backing up the file structure of a partition.
I have a 4.5 TB external WD_Black drive with tones of bad sectors and also badly formatted (for large files -> 1MB sector) and since I don't have that spare space to empty the drive, I want to move half of the data out of it, format that part, move data back on it, and repeat the process on the other half. As I recall from my systems teacher, the table always sits at the beginning of the partition, so if I make the new partition, once I extend it to the other empty half, the table will remain in the middle black circled area.
Is there a way to make a backup of it, in case something goes wrong, and maybe even move it that way back to the beginning?
I already searched here and on google and all I could find is only table recovery once busted.

Upon investigating a bit more, the reason I can't copy files and Auslogics sees them as unmovable appears to be due to CRC errors, I have doubts there are bad sectors. The reason this happened (as far as I can think of) is because of the drive technology. It's an SMR drive (has 2TB actually but writes data on top of previous data to reach that 4.5TB cap) and combined with some power-loss and bad RAM (BSOD) corrupted the data probably while jellyfin was touching it, plus it was sitting on the top exhaust an reached 60ºC one time also corrupting the data.
So I still want to try and reformat it and retest it bit by bit (not the storage unit :D) but I need the possibility to backup where the files are located in the table. I should also mention it's an exFAT not NTFS.

For what it is worth; a drive that has begun to "create" bad block is just simply dying, it may take some time - or fail in an important system area and fall off the cliff the next minute. One cannot tell... for your own sanity - look into replacing it as soon as possible; don't even try to revitalize it.

I would even recommend reading out all the data in one go with e.g. dd (Linux) and then handle / read the data from the copy only.

Reading the question it seems like you're confusing several different kinds of "tables"... You're saying "partition table" but it seems that you're really talking about the file allocation table in FAT?

@grawity It's possible, although isn't one part of the other? I always thought the file allocation table is part of the partitions table, but I'll go and look it now. Either way, since I'm going to mess with the partition splitting it and then extending it, I need a way to make sure the files remaining on the old partition don't get screwed and rebuild it in case it fails.

No, they're completely different and unrelated things.

Yeah, I just looked it up, sorry about the confusion, it's the FAT that I'm interested in backing up then :D

@Ramhound I've seen 8TB SMR disks, so it's not uncommon link

@Ramhound I can safely say that it is 4.5 since my new 4TB CMR drive can't take all the data from it, and everything on it is still intact and usable being that I only had 100GB left on it. That's why I need to play with the partitions on it and move surplus data is stages. The only problem is I can't copy the data on another drive by traditional means, and also, we are deviating from the subject...
